# Magento Customer Registration Notification Email Sent to Admin

Tags: magento-1.9, register, order-email

Is there an easy solution for the admin to receive a notification email every time someone registers to the store?

Comment: Have a look on this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310894/email-notification-when-a-new-customer-has-been-added-magento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an observer on the `customer_register_success` event.

Then access the customer object in your model:

```
public function notify_function($observer) 

{

$customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();

//Do whatever you want here
}
```

Please check below link for more information:
 http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-custom-emails/

You can also use:

The [customer activation](https://github.com/Vinai/customer-activation) module from Vinai not only has this functionality but also allows you to specify the template used when emailing the admin user on customer registration.

Answer (score 0):

The question title and body do not match up for this question too well!

Setting up your server to reliably send emails is way beyond the scope of Magento SE, however, a brief over view of things to check given a default setup.

Is there some SPF record on there?

Is the server trying to use IPv6?

What is the reverse PTR say it is?

Now for the Magento specific part...

Some of the default Magento templates get easily flagged as spam and all you need to do is to change the templates in relatively minor ways to fix it. Sending the plaintext password out does not help, nor does the 'dear whomever' intro. Spring back what you have and see if it goes any better.

Also check the /var/log/syslog files, there is a mail log but, by default on some systems (looking at you, Ubuntu) the log goes to syslog whether you wanted it to or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can try free extensions which are easy to integrate 
have a look at this extension

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-registration-notification.html
[extension][1]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Magento 2 and want to stay informed about all the events in your store, you can try this extension:http://store.magenest.com/magento-2-admin-email-notification.html

It cover a lots of key events like new registration, new order, new review... The email you receive will also contain basic information about the event. Here is a template email:[image]
Feel free to have a look there (it is compatible with 2.1 too!).